# Returning HTML fragments from vanilla php backend to htmx

Tags: php, laravel, htmx

I wonder if there is a way to achieve functionality similar to Twig or Blade for rendering HTML fragments, without installing them solely for that purpose because templating engines are quiet large.

Twig approach

```
$template->renderBlock('block_name', ['the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here']);
```

Blade has a similar approach; you use @fragment to name HTML fragments in the view, then target them in the controller."

I found two approaches, but none of them is ideal; each one has some drawbacks:

**Returning HTML as a string to the client:**
Problems:

- Impractical
- Hard to maintain
- Not considered good practice

**Creating template files**

- Making those files where I insert the HTML needed to generate and include them in the controller - method handling that. See the code below for clarification.

Problem:

- Difficult to maintain and manage because there will be too many template files if the app grows larger

ProductController.php

```
public function searchByName(): void
    {
        if (!isset($_GET['search_value'])) {
            $products = $this->productModel->getAll();
            $this->renderFragment('/productCard.php', ['products' => $products]);
        }

        $products = $this->productModel->searchByName($_GET['search_value']);

        if (!isset($products)) $this->renderFragment('/notFoundProduct.php');

        $this->renderFragment('/productCard.php', ['products' => $products]);
    }
```

renderFragment method from Controller class

```
protected function renderFragment(string $path, array $values = []): void
    {
        extract($values);
        require_once __DIR__ . '/../../view/fragments' . $path;
        exit();
    }
```

productCard.php - template file

```
<?php foreach ($products as $item) : ?>
        <div>
            <img src="<?= BASE_URL.$item['image'] ?>" alt="Plant in a pot">
            <p><?= $item['name'] ?></p>
            <p><?= $item['quantity'] ?> left</p>
            <p>$<?= $item['price'] ?></p>
        </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

shop.php - view file

```
<input hx-get="<?= BASE_URL ?>/product-search" hx-trigger="load, keyup change delay:500ms" hx-target="#search-results" name="search_value">

<div id="search-results" class="mt-5 row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 row-cols-sm-2 g-4">
   <!-- productCard.php -->
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome! If I understand correctly, you like your current approach, but want to store multiple fragments per file?

Comment: My ideal approach would be to have something similar to Blade or Twig, as shown here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#rendering-blade-fragments

However, I'm open to new approaches. Having multiple fragments in one file is also a good idea, but you'll need something like what Blade offers to target each one of them in order to choose which one you want to use.

Comment: Is size really a problem? Even "large" code libraries are small compared to other assets like images. However, if you want to roll your own, [the DOM function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) may be a place to start. Flexible, but kind of complicated.